# Define an NavigationInstruction that waits until a promise returns

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, aurelia

How can we define an NavigationInstruction that waits until a promise returns?

```
let loginRedirectRoute: RouteConfig = {
    name: "openIdRedirectRoute",
    navigationStrategy: (instruction: NavigationInstruction) => {
        this.loginRedirectHandler().then(() => {
            instruction.config.moduleId = openIdConfiguration.LoginRedirectModuleId;
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.error(err.message);
        });
    },
    route: this.getPath(openIdConfiguration.UserManagerSettings.redirect_uri),
};
```

The above does not work. It only works if we call instruction.config.moduleId... synchronously.

In other words, we need a navigation strategy that does something after a promise returns.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inner function is not returning a Promise. Try

```
this.loginRedirectHandler().then(() => {
    return instruction.config.moduleId = openIdConfiguration.LoginRedirectModuleId;
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err.message);
});
```

Remember that

- `.then(() => { return do_this(); })` chains a Promise,
- `.then(() => do_this());` chains a Promise,
- `.then(() => { do_this(); })` does NOT.

```js
var foo = 0;

function do_this(bar) {
  console.log("call " + foo + " passed " + bar);
  foo++;
  bar++;
  return bar;
}

var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(0);
  }, 500);
});

promise
  .then((bar) => { return do_this(bar); }) /* 1 */
  .then((bar) => do_this(bar)) /* 2 */
  .then((bar) => { do_this(bar); }) /* 3 */
  .then((bar) => do_this(bar)); /* undefined */
```

Comment: The code works with both `{ do_this(); }` and `do_this()`. Why do both work? Is chaining a Promise not necessary in this particular instance?

Comment: Late response...
If the next step doesn't require the results of the previous Promise, it doesn't matter that the inner method doesn't return a Promise. It simply means the next step will execute immediately without waiting for the previous Promise to resolve.